# Serialize set with comparator using Gson

Tags: java, gson

I need to serialize a class that contains a TreeSet for which it has a custom comparator (byte[] not being comparable).

When I attempt to deserialize the class with Gson (v2.3.1) I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)....
```

So the TreeSet is not deserialized using the comparator.

The class looks like this:

```
public class In {

    private final SortedSet<byte[]> keys = new TreeSet<>(new ByteKeyComparator());

}
```

Is there a way to make Gson understand that it needs a comparator for this set?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29

Comment: @Thillakan - The link to the javadoc for TreeSet is not very helpful.  I know it will throw a ClassCastException if something is added that can't be compared. That's why I initialize it with a byte[] Comparator. This is a serialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's a serialization bug. However, it has nothing to do with Gson, and actually your custom comparator *is* being retained.

The problem lies in the implementation of `TreeMap.put(K,V)` combined with the deserialization behavior of an empty TreeSet, which results in the backing map having a null `root`. If the TreeMap's root node is null and you put a key/value pair, it ignores the configured comparator.

To solve your problem, skip serializing empty `TreeSet`s.

Comment: The error occurs with TreeSets that are not empty.  I'm starting to think the issue is type erasure of class Comparator<byte[]>

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I made a mistake. It is likely you are correct, that Gson is not serializing or deserializing the comparator. Do you see anything that looks like a comparator in the JSON output?

Comment: Good question. No, it's not serialized. I tried to force it to be serialize by including it as a field, but then it serializes as ""byteKeyComparator":{},".  Which is what you would expect, since it has no attributes.  I guess I'll have to pass my byte arrays as a list and sort them on the server side.  Thanks.